# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: field)

Tags: javascript, rails-api

I am stuck on this backend issue and cannot understand why it is not defined.
The id is passed into the params at the start of the `handledFormSubmit` function, but when the field is passed into a const and defined as `const field = Field.findyById(id);` => the output of field is then undefined.

Why is it losing its value? (attached the screenshot of the event in the DOM below for more information)

**ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: field):**

Controller:

```
def index
  @fields = Field.all
  render json: @fields
end

def update
  @field = Field.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @field.update(field_params)

  if @field.save
    render json: @field, status: :accepted
  else
    render json: { errors: @field.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessible_entity
  end
end

private

def field_params
  params.require(:field).permit(:id, :name, :coordinates, :locations)
end
```

Adapter:

```
fetchFields() {
    return this.get(`${this.baseUrl}/fields`);
}

updateField(id, input) {
    return this.patch(`${this.baseUrl}/fields/${id}`, input);
}

get(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
}

patch(url, input) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: this.headers,
        input: JSON.stringify(input),
    }).then(res => res.json());
}
```

App:

```
handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    const field = Field.findById(id);
    const coordinates= e.target.querySelector('input').value

    const inputJSON = { name, coordinates };
    this.adapter.updateField(field.id, inputJSON).then(updatedField => {
      const field = Field.findById(updatedField.id);
      field.update(updatedField);
      this.addFields();
    });
  }

handleEditClick(e) {
    const id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
    const field = Field.findById(id);
    document.querySelector('#update').innerHTML = field.renderUpdateForm();
}
```

[image of dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmX8L.png)

Comment: How does the `Field.findyById` look like?

Comment: `static findById(id) {
    return this.all.find(field => field.id === id);
  }
}`

Comment: @jesseb maybe it's a problem with the strict equality `field.id === id`. Did you try to console log the `typeof` of each ?

Comment: patch(url, input) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: this.headers,
       **input: JSON.stringify(input)**,
    }).then(res => res.json());
}

My issue was the use of "input" inside the Patch req after headers.  I thought i was passing in a variable and did not realize the backend was looking for body and this was not dynamic. Thank you for helping me guys. @SebastianKaczmarek